# The function of liking and disliking the post does not work in the frontend (react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on social media website project for practising purpose and I made the liking and disliking posts well and when i press like post it work very fine and the icon change to fill icon, but when I refresh the page, the like disappears as if it never existed I don't know why,
I have tried doing a like from the backend and it works fine and even the icon changes on the page when I do it from the backend, This means that the problem is in the front-end code.

This is the liking code from post component:

```
const [like, setLike] = useState([post.like.includes(userId) ? anotherLikeIcon : likeIcon]);
const [count, setCount] = useState(post.like.length);

const handleLike = async() => {


if(like == likeIcon){
        await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post._id}/like`, 
        {
            method:"PUT", 
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':"application/Json",
                token:accessToken
            }})
        setLike(anotherLikeIcon);
        setCount(count+1)
    } else {
        await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post._id}/like`, 
        {
            method:"PUT", 
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':"application/Json",
                token:accessToken
            }})
        setLike(likeIcon);
        setCount(count-1)
    }
}
```

Just to know I put the token in the variable `accessToken` in the component.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be fetching the likes count after each like or unlike, also consider using persistent storage such as local storage or a cookie to save like state and count even after refreshing.
This is a basic approach that could help you:

```
// Initial state
const [like, setLike] = useState(post.like.includes(userId));
const [count, setCount] = useState(post.like.length);

// Check for like status in local storage on component mount
useEffect(() => {
  const storedLike = localStorage.getItem(`like_${post._id}`);
  if (storedLike !== null) {
    setLike(JSON.parse(storedLike));
  }
}, []);

const handleLike = async () => {
  if (!like) {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post._id}/like`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: accessToken
      }
    });
    setCount(count + 1);
  } else {
    // Remove like on the backend
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post._id}/like`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: accessToken
      }
    });
    setCount(count - 1);
  }

  // Toggle the like state in local storage
  localStorage.setItem(`like_${post._id}`, JSON.stringify(!like));

  // Toggle the like state in the component
  setLike(!like);
};
```

I believe there is better way to handle that but this workaround may help you solve your problem, Good luck mate.